# Getting SSLCertVerificationError during Web Scrapping with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, ssl-certificate, data-analysis

I'm trying to scrape data from Amazon's website for a project using Python and the beautifulsoup library, but I'm encountering an SSLCertVerificationError. Despite my efforts to disable the warning using the urllib3 library (which I learned about from YouTube), I am still facing this problem. Can anyone please help me with this error. Here is the code I'm using:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import urllib3
import certifi


# Disable insecure request warnings
requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings()
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CA_BUNDLE = certifi.where()

# Function to extract Product Title
def get_title(soup):

    try:
        # Outer Tag Object
        title = soup.find("span", attrs={"id":'productTitle'})
        
        # Inner NavigatableString Object
        title_value = title.text

        # Title as a string value
        title_string = title_value.strip()

    except AttributeError:
        title_string = ""

    return title_string

# Function to extract Product Price
def get_price(soup):

    try:
        price = soup.find("span", attrs={'class':'a-price aok-align-center reinventPricePriceToPayMargin priceToPay'}).find("span", attrs={'class' : "a-offscreen"}).text.strip()

    except AttributeError:

        try:
            # If there is some deal price
            price = soup.find("span", attrs={'class':'a-price a-text-price'}).find("span", attrs={'class' : "a-offscreen"}).text.strip()

        except:
            price = ""

    return price

# Function to extract Product Rating
def get_rating(soup):

    try:
        rating = soup.find("span", attrs={'class':'a-icon a-icon-star a-star-4 cm-cr-review-stars-spacing-big'}).string.strip()
    
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            rating = soup.find("span", attrs={'class':'a-icon-alt'}).text.strip()
        except:
            rating = "" 

    return rating

# Function to extract Number of User Reviews
def get_review_count(soup):
    try:
        review_count = soup.find("span", attrs={'id':'acrCustomerReviewText'}).string.strip()

    except AttributeError:
        review_count = ""   

    return review_count

# Function to extract Availability Status
def get_availability(soup):
    try:
        available = soup.find("div", attrs={'id':'availability'})
        available = available.find("span").string.strip()

    except AttributeError:
        available = "Not Available" 

    return available
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Add User Agent 
    HEADERS = ({'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/115.0.1901.188', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})

    # The webpage URL
    url = "https://www.amazon.in/s?i=electronics&bbn=1389432031&rh=n%3A1389432031%2Cp_n_condition-type%3A8609960031%2Cp_36%3A1500000-2000000&pf_rd_i=1389401031&pf_rd_m=A1K21FY43GMZF8&pf_rd_p=d0528e32-aebf-4fa6-8321-c73776cafad7&pf_rd_r=TG92YM2SPG3CH9XV8DXS&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-8&pf_rd_t=101&ref=s9_acss_bw_cg_Budget_2c1_w"

    # HTTP Request
    response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, verify=False)

    # Check the response code 
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Soup Object containing all data
        soup = bs(response.content, "html.parser")

        # Fetch links as List of Tag Objects
        links = soup.find_all("a", attrs={'class':'a-link-normal s-underline-text s-underline-link-text s-link-style a-text-normal'})

        # Store the links
        links_list = []
        
        # Loop for extracting links from Tag Objects
        for link in links:
                links_list.append(link.get('href'))

        d = {"title":[], "price":[], "rating":[], "reviews":[],"availability":[]}
        
        # Loop for extracting product details from each link 
        for link in links_list:
            new_webpage = requests.get("https://www.amazon.in" + link, headers=HEADERS)

            new_soup = bs(new_webpage.content, "html.parser")

            # Function calls to display all necessary product information
            d['title'].append(get_title(new_soup))
            d['price'].append(get_price(new_soup))
            d['rating'].append(get_rating(new_soup))
            d['reviews'].append(get_review_count(new_soup))
            d['availability'].append(get_availability(new_soup))

        
        amazon_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d)
        amazon_df['title'].replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)
        amazon_df = amazon_df.dropna(subset=['title'])
        amazon_df.to_csv("amazon_data.csv", header=True, index=False)
    else:
        print("Error in fetching data from the web. Status Code: {response.status_code}")
```